# How do you run cura 15.04.6 on Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: 19.10

I just installed Ubuntu 19.10. I am also very new to Linux; this is my first install ever. I need to be able to use my robo r1+ 3D printer from this computer. I have used Cura before and I am familiar with the way it works. 15.04.6 works best with my printer so far.

How do I make cura 15.04.6 run on Ubuntu 19.10?

Comment: See https://community.ultimaker.com/topic/15172-install-cura-in-linux/   https://ultimaker.com/en/resources/manuals  and https://ultimaker.com/software/ultimaker-cura

Comment: I used all the links provided. I will try the help from the ultimaker community. I already have the software download. I am just not sure where I went wrong trying to make it work.

Comment: See here:
https://community.ultimaker.com/topic/29229-legacy-cura-version-150406/

http://dulek.net/work/ultimaker/